# Dojo byId() method

Tags: javascript, html, xml, jsf

Does anybody know, how dojo.byId() method searches the specified DOM node? It seems to search recursively from the current DOM level and the goes up.
Is it true?

I have tried to search the HTML element, (which is on the same DOM level) with a specified id with it. As far as i am conserned (maybe it is incorrect) HTML rewrites id in such a way: if the element's id is "test" and it is in the form "form1" the id is form1:test (is it true)? dojo.byId() found it (dojo.byId() was in the same form).
BUT, when I tried to search the JSF element () in such a way (dojo.byId() in the same form), the search failed.

Please, help me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the JSF ids. Can you see the html source-code generated by your JSF page? Search for the element you are trying to find and see if JSF does not prepended or appended some code to the original id